# Alerts with several expressions

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm a thinking of a concept in terms how to define alerts based on latency.
Essentially I would need that for the blackbox exporter alerts.
Based on the reponse time I won't have alert stating the current status of the connection.

```
good connection
slow connection
no connection
```

Is there a way to define one rule which will evalute more then 1 expression and fire an alarm with specific summary and labels depending on the expression that fires?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is rather 'no' than 'yes'. Annotations are static, whatever you wrote in it will be there for each trigger. You can, however, execute queries in annotations, but I guess bringing there any logic would be an overkill. To show you the complexity, consider this annotation:

```yaml
# get error codes that occurred during last 5 minutes in the firing service
error_codes: >-
  Error code(s): {{ range printf `sum(increase(request_duration_seconds_count{status=~"5..",hostname="%s",service="%s"}[5m])) by (status) > 0` .Labels.hostname .Labels.service | query | sortByLabel "status" }}{{ .Labels.status }} {{ end }}
```

The situation with labels is somewhat the same. Those labels you write in alert under `labels:` key are static. But you can mess with labels in alert expression by joining, rewriting, adding new, etc. Just as with annotations, this will add a lot of unreasonable complexity, which will make you unsure whether you actually get an alert or there is bug that will let you down under some circumstances.

##### My advice is to Keep It Simple, Stupid. Make several alerts but let them be easy to understand, customise, and fix.